# How can I install pdal or liblas on google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, liblas, pdal

I need to read .las file and to run the code via google colab.

I have tried several libraries as lilbas and pdal. However when trying to import them, I have some errors that I have difficulties to solve.

In order to install the libraries, i have runned the following codes:
!pip install liblas
or 
!pip install pydal

However I got following errors:
For liblas:
     OSError: liblas_c.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

For pdal:
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/67/338c4164a02b1bb0ecb34adca254b29e88c6c3ed874402d2cd67f5c611a5/PDAL-2.1.8.tar.gz
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-tiflm77w/pdal/

Could you help me?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can use Laspy library to work with LAS files.